# Disable warnings in Xcode from frameworks

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I have imported the three20 project into my project, and when I upgraded to Xcode 4.2 with iOS 5, a bunch of warnings appeared in the project.

I don't care about them, but they make a lot of noise, and it's easy to miss any real warnings in my project now.  Is there a way to disable warnings for those specific libraries?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

1. If your third-party libraries are added as a separate target, you can check `Inhibit all warnings` for that specific target to turn all warnings off.
2. If your library is added as plain source files to your current target, you can set `-w` compiler flag for individual sources to mute all warnings in them. You have to go to `Build phases` menu of your target configuration and set this flag for each source file in `Compile Sources` section by double clicking on each file end entering `-w` flag.
   [image]

Comment: This is absolutely the correct approach. Do not modify 3rdparty code, and do not turn off warnings globally. Another similar approach is to move the 3rdparty code into a separate project and build a static lib. That way it can have its own build settings.

Comment: Every once in a while, I bumble my way into an answer that I wish I could upvote at least a few times. This is one of those times.

Comment: [This article](http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2013/02/selectively-disabling-warnings-with-xcode-compiler-flags/) gives some additional details on the individual files flags. They suggest using `-w -Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-checker`

Comment: I tried this in Xcode 7.2.1 and got an error message suggesting that I replace `-analyzer-disable-checker` with `-analyzer-disable-all-checks`.

Comment: What if the libraries are static? I only have a thirdPartyLibraryFile.a under the "Build Phases" > "Link Binary With Libraries". There is no compiler flags option under that section.

Comment: As an addition: If the target uses Swift, you should also set `Suppress Warnings` in the `Swift Compiler - Warning Policies` to `Yes`.

Answer (score 20):

If you are using pods, you can add this to your podfile to prevent warnings logging:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS'] = "YES"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The shorter solution is to add `inhibit_all_warnings!` up top, as per: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208202/ignore-xcode-warnings-when-using-cocoapods

Comment: Note that adding the `inhibit_all_warnings!` flag is not recommended, since it will be overridden whenever `pod install` is executed.  I'd prefer setting in the Podfile

Answer (score 8):

If the warnings come from the included library or framework header files, you can wrap that include statements like this:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wnullability-completeness"
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Put your warning flag on the second line above. You can lookup a warning flags here: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html

Answer (score 0):

If the warnings are coming from a framework (for me it was Rollbar) that was added with Carthage:

1. Add a new framework target (i.e. RollbarWrapper) to your project and embed it within your application target

[image]

2. Drag the built framework from `Carthage/Build/<platform>` into Xcode, adding it to the dummy/wrapper framework you just created (RollbarWrapper)

[image]

3. Make sure that the framework (Rollbar) is added to the dummy/wrapper framework (RollbarWrapper) target's Frameworks and Libraries section and is set to Do Not Embed

[image]

4. Go to the Build Settings for the dummy/wrapper framework (RollbarWrapper) and set "Inhibit All Warnings" to **Yes**
5. Next, add the framework (Rollbar) to your application target's Frameworks, Libraries, & Embedded Content section and set to Do Not Embed

[image]

6. Finally, for the application target, do the [normal Carthage setup](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#adding-frameworks-to-an-application) (i.e. create a new Run Script Phase to execute the `copy-frameworks` script to copy the Rollbar framework)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a third-party static library (`libSomething.a`) and importing the headers from that library, this works to silence all warnings as of Xcode 15:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Weverything"
#include "someHeader.h"
#include "someOtherHeader.h"
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

(I saw some older comments that `-Weverything` didn't work on older Xcode versions, but it does on 15 at least.) This is much more convenient than looking up individual warning flags in Clang's list of 19,457 flags.