# How to kill the "Unknown attribute 'flatten' ignored" warning?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

There is some 3rd party `c` code included in an iOS project:

```
static int __attribute__((flatten)) f(struct node *node)
```

and Xcode gives a warning:

```
Unknown attribute 'flatten' ignored
```

What's the best way to kill this warning, without modifying the original source file?

Comment: An option: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8580123/88597

Answer (score 2):

Use `#pragma` directives around the `#include` of that file to ignore the appropriate warning (-Wunknown-attributes) or search your build settings and see if it the warning is listed there and disable it.

Comment: Additionally, it might be a good idea to surround that with `#pragma clang diagnostics push` and `pop` (see the [clang manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-via-pragmas).

Comment: @DarkDust That is what my first suggestion was >_>