# How can I suppress compiler warnings in Xcode 5 caused by a 3rd party framework?

Tags: xcode

I have a 3rd party framework that I have imported into my project, and it is causing compiler warnings to show up from issues in its header files. I do not want to have to change the 3rd party code, as it will likely change in the near future. I found this post:

[Disable warnings in Xcode from frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997636/disable-warnings-in-xcode-from-frameworks)

Which talks about how to turn off warnings on a per-file or per-project basis, but I am not certain how to do this for a framework. This is because the files are technically there but Xcode does not show them in the compiled sources section.

Does anyone know of a way to ignore compiler warnings for an included framework?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you would like to disable them?

Comment: I do not own nor have rights to make changes to the framework, so I can not fix them myself. Also, they inflate the number of warnings that actually exist in my team's code.

Comment: Side note - be sure to file a bug report with the framework author.

Comment: can you disable warnings from the header file?

Comment: That thought had occured to me, even though this would mean I would be altering the 3rd party's code (which is never really a good idea...). There are several header files included in the framework, but I have tried adding #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-w" (with the appropriate push before this and pop at the end of the header file) but the errors warnings are still present when I build.

Comment: I'd also love a solution to this for frameworks specifically.

Answer (score 5):

We've fixed same problem with a 3rd party framework warnings in header files by including problematic files in our pre-compiled header (.pch) with a proper pragma mark.

i.e.

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmismatched-tags"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wreorder"

#import <ComponentKit/CKComponentViewConfiguration.h>
#import <ComponentKit/CKArrayControllerChangeset.h>
#import <ComponentKit/CKComponentDataSource.h>
#import <ComponentKit/CKComponentBoundsAnimation.h>

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```