# How do you hide the warnings in React Native iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, react-native, show-hide

I just upgraded my React Native and now the iOS simulator has a bunch of warnings. Besides fixing them, how do I hide these warnings so that I can see what's underneath?

Answer (score 424, accepted):

According to React Native [Documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging#logbox), you can hide warning messages by setting `disableYellowBox` to `true` like this:

```
console.disableYellowBox = true;
```

#### Update: React Native 0.63+

`console.disableYellowBox` is removed and now you can use:

```
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';
LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Warning: ...']); // Ignore log notification by message
LogBox.ignoreAllLogs();//Ignore all log notifications
```

to ignore all log notifications

Comment: this worked for me, but not the other answers that said console.ignoredYellowBox = [...];

Comment: Sorry, but where do you add console.disableYellowBox = true ?

Comment: @Mike, any place in your script, when you want to disable yellow box.

Comment: A good place to put it is on the constructor of RootContainer component!

Comment: Placing it in the `App.js` (or `Routes.js` depending on your structure) works well as well.

Comment: `console.disableYellowBox` has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use LogBox.ignoreAllLogs(value) instead. https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging.html#warnings

Answer (score 150):

A better way to selectively hide certain warnings (that indefinitely show up after an upgrade to the latest and greatest RN version) is to set [console.ignoredYellowBox](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/ReactNative/YellowBox.js) in a common JS file in your project. For example, after upgrading my project today to RN 0.25.1 I was seeing a lot of...

**Warning: ReactNative.createElement is deprecated...**

I still want to be able to see helpful warnings and error messages from React-Native, but I want to squash this particular warning because it's coming from an external npm library that hasn't yet incorporated the breaking changes in RN 0.25. So in my App.js I add this line...

```
// RN >= 0.63
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';

LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Warning: ...']);

// RN >= 0.52
import {YellowBox} from 'react-native';

YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: ReactNative.createElement']);

// RN < 0.52
console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Warning: ReactNative.createElement'];
```

This way I still get other errors and warning helpful for my dev environment, but I no longer see that particular one.

Comment: Perfect fix for me, though I had the same "ReactNative.createElement is deprecated" warning.

Comment: how much of the error message should you write to ignore it?

Comment: This answer needs update . YelloBox is not part of react-native anymore.

Comment: it supports both regexp and substrings, but typescript types only have strings :(

Comment: Does anyone knows if React Native Web forwards this for web console. Can't get it to work on web yet.

Answer (score 28):

To disable the yellow box place

```
console.disableYellowBox = true;
```

anywhere in your application. Typically in the root file so it will apply to both iOS and Android.

For example

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
     render() {
          console.disableYellowBox = true;
          return (<View></View>);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

**`add this line in your app main screen.`**

> console.disableYellowBox = true;

for example:- in index.js file

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import './src/utils';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
console.disableYellowBox = true;
```

Answer (score 18):

For me below lines worked currently I am using react native 0.64

```
  import { LogBox } from 'react-native';

  LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Warning: ...']); //Hide warnings

  LogBox.ignoreAllLogs();//Hide all warning notifications on front-end
```

When adding your warning to specify exactly which warning to suppress, you need to *exactly* add the warning message, like so (random example)

```
LogBox.ignoreLogs([
  'Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key `tintColor` supplied to `Text`.',
]);
```

Using single quotes instead of backticks around `tintColor` or `Text`, for example, will not work.

Answer (score 15):

In your app.js file under any component's lifecycle method.like in componentDidmount()
you have to add both of these,excluding any will not work.

```
console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Warning: Each', 'Warning: Failed'];
console.disableYellowBox = true;
```

Comment: That is not true, something is going on in your project. One line says "ignore this list of warnings" (which is the most precise way to do it), one line says "ignore all warnings" (which is a really blunt way to do it). I only have the first line for instance, and it suppresses my warnings perfectly.

Answer (score 13):

Add the following code in your **index.js** file

console.disableYellowBox = true;

```
    import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
    import App from './App';
    import {name as appName} from './app.json';

    console.disableYellowBox = true;



AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Answer (score 12):

#### If You're Trying to *Quickly* Demo the App.

If you want to hide them in a particular build because you're doing a demo or something, you can edit your Xcode scheme to make it a release build and these yellow warnings will not show up. Additionally, your app will run much faster.

You can edit the Scheme for your simulator and real device by doing the following:

1. In Project in XCode.
2. `Product` > `Scheme` > `Edit Scheme...`
3. Change `Build Configuration` from `Debug` to `Release`.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. In `Release`: no warning, and faster app !

Comment: You don't get any debug features in `Release`

Comment: @PhilAndrews I agree! I don't know I posted this way back when but there are enough people that find it useful that I'll leave it. I must have been trying to demo the app to somebody and wanted to get rid of yellow warnings, in which case, this is the right way to go.

Answer (score 11):

For those coming this way trying to disable red warnings from the console, that give absolutely useless information, as of feb/17, you can add this line of code somewhere

`console.error = (error) => error.apply;`

Disables all `console.error`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even realize that my console error was the reason that red screen was popping up. I thought something was wrong with try/catch not working :o.

Answer (score 11):

RN >= 0.62

```
import {LogBox} from 'react-native'
```

under the import, add

```
LogBox.ignoreLogs(['...']);
```

instead of '...',
you can write the warnings you want to hide.
For instance,
I had the warning VirtualizedLists should never be ....
then I can write as

```
LogBox.ignoreLogs(['VirtualizedLists']);
```

if you want to add another error, you can write as

```
LogBox.ignoreLogs(['VirtualizedLists','Warning:...']);
```

Answer (score 6):

console.disableYellowBox = true;

this worked for application level Put it anywhere in index.js file

Answer (score 5):

I found that even when I disabled specific warnings (yellow-box messages) using the above mentioned methods, the warnings *were* disabled on my mobile device, but they were still being logged to my console, which was very annoying and distracting.

To prevent warnings from being logged to your console, you can simply override the `warn` method on the `console` object.

```
// This will prevent all warnings from being logged
console.warn = () => {};
```

It is even possible to disable only specific warnings by testing the provided message:

```
// Hold a reference to the original function so that it can be called later
const originalWarn = console.warn;

console.warn = (message, ...optionalParams) => {
  // Insure that we don't try to perform any string-only operations on
  // a non-string type:
  if (typeof message === 'string') {
    // Check if the message contains the blacklisted substring
    if (/Your blacklisted substring goes here/g.test(message))
    {
      // Don't log the value
      return;
    }
  }

  // Otherwise delegate to the original 'console.warn' function
  originalWarn(message, ...optionalParams);
};
```

If you can't (or don't want to) use a Regular Expression to test the string, the `indexOf` method will work just as well:

```
// An index of -1 will be returned if the blacklisted substring was NOT found
if (message.indexOf('Your blacklisted substring goes here') > -1) {
  // Don't log the message
  return;
}
```

Be aware that this technique will filter **all** messages that go through the `warn` function regardless of where they originated from.
Because of this, be careful that you do not specify an overly generous blacklist that will suppress other meaningful errors that may originate from somewhere other than React Native.

Also, I believe that React Native uses the `console.error` method to log errors (red-box messages), so I'm assuming that this technique could be used to filter out specific errors as well.

Answer (score 5):

**Add in app.js**

import LogBox from React Native

import {LogBox} from 'react-native';

and then..

LogBox.ignoreAllLogs()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

To disable the yellow box place `console.disableYellowBox = true;` anywhere in your application. Typically in the root file so it will apply to both iOS and Android.

For get more details please check [official document](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#yellowbox-redbox)

Answer (score 4):

console.disableYellowBox = true;

Answer (score 3):

**It works fine after it has been added**

```
//app.js

import { LogBox } from 'react-native'; 

 useEffect(() => {
    LogBox.ignoreAllLogs(true)
 }, [])
```

https://reactnative.dev/blog/2020/07/06/version-0.63

Answer (score 2):

Create an warnings file separately, then we can add multiple alerts there

Like this IgnoreWarnings.js

```
import { LogBox } from "react-native";

if (__DEV__) {
  const ignoreWarns = [
    "EventEmitter.removeListener",
    "[fuego-swr-keys-from-collection-path]",
    "Setting a timer for a long period of time",
    "ViewPropTypes will be removed from React Native",
    "AsyncStorage has been extracted from react-native",
    "exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",
    "Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state.",
    "VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews",
    "Remote debugger"
  ];

  const warn = console.warn;
  console.warn = (...arg) => {
    for (const warning of ignoreWarns) {
      if (arg[0].startsWith(warning)) {
        return;
      }
    }
    warn(...arg);
  };
  LogBox.ignoreLogs(ignoreWarns);
}
```

import the IgnoreWarnings file in the navigation or app.js file like this

```
import "../helpers/IgnoreWarnings";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **AppDelegate.m** file you can change this line :

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

and replace `dev=true` by `dev=false` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

#### Related: Suppress Xcode warnings from React Native library

*(but not for your own code)*

**why:** when initialising a new RN-app, the Xcode project contains closer to 100 warnings that is distracting noise (but probably harmless otherwise)

**solution:** set *inhibit all warnings* to *yes* under *Build Settings* for the relevant targets.

[image]

[Disable warnings in Xcode from frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997636/disable-warnings-in-xcode-from-frameworks)

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11736

Comment: also; for logic errors; see "-Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-all-checks"

Comment: Original question was about in-app warning (ie. yellow box), I found this question when trying to clean up the Xcode project warnings. Why downvote? see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299352/answering-a-related-question

Answer (score 0):

I like to put the console.disableYellowBox = true on the file root, like App.
But this just when im on the development phase.

Answer (score 0):

console.error = (error) => error.apply; // in the index.js

Some times rn 0.66 does not works Logbox. especially for VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews.

And also ignore red warnings.