# How to hide warning comes from libraries in xcode that installed without using pods?

Tags: ios, xcode, swrevealviewcontroller

I need to use SWRevealViewController to make slide out menu navigation
but, the pod is no longer updated. so it will give a lot of warning in xcode.

even though it seems okay to use this pod, but the warnings from xcode is ugly, I want to hide it.

if the pod is installed using cocoapod, it can be done using this line in podfile

```
# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!
```

but how about the file that imported manually like SWRevealViewController ?

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8580123/2776008

Comment: yes but thats too old xcode, I am new in iOS Development, and it confuses me :(

Comment: It's old Xcode version, but everything is same. You can try to do it